# VSCode, how to source environment variable files like setup.bash?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

So I'm working with WSL, ROS, and VSCode.

When working on Ubuntu, I would just source /opt/ros/ros-distro/setup.bash before running VsCode to source the environment variables.

When working with WSL, I need a way to run the source setup.bash from already opened VSCode. Running source command on integrated terminal doesn't seem to source environment to VSCode itself.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Most likely not, a child can't change the environment of a parent process, the terminal is the child and VSC is the parent

Comment: Why can you NOT source before running vscode in WSL ?

Comment: Because VSCode runs on the host and opens the project inside the WSL as if it was a remote machine.